# Is there a personal Spam Trap / DNSBL solution?

Tags: microsoft-exchange, spam, email-server

I administer some e-mail servers, and something I've been looking for for a while is some way to create my own local DNSBL server, based on Spam Traps set by me.

Public DNSBL services such as Spamhaus won't block most spam that lands on my servers, because those spammers aparently only send e-mails to addresses specific to my country, and this way they seem to avoid their Spam Traps.

I receive tons of spam on addresses that once could be found on HTML source code of my clients' websites, and they could easily be used as perfect Spam Traps to disinfect my mailboxes from this cancer. Howover, I could never find any software that makes that happen.

Does anyone know software that allows me to create a DNSBL or any similar solution that makes that possible?

I'm tagging this as Exchange Server but the platform doesn't matter. If making my mail go through a Postfix server first will solve my problem I will make that happen.

Comment: With postfix that's almost easy (I'm doing that, and it works really well) – but that would make your question rather a "how-to" (off-topic here – but should fit on serverfault; if you post it there and ping me with the URL, e.g. in another comment here, I happily outline it over there. Oh wait, a more complex setup is already described there: [How do I spamtrap with Postfix?](http://serverfault.com/q/67507/145213) – so make sure to search before posting; my setup is rather simple and assumes you just want to setup a bunch of spamtrap addresses you already know, much easier and less complex).

Comment: OK, [here you go](http://serverfault.com/a/739819/145213) :)